# Clear GridView without using the EmptyDataTemplate message

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net page with a `GridView` control (id = `GeneralGridView`), that has an `EmptyDataTemplate`:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <strong>No records found!</strong>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

When I first load the page, nothing is bound to the `GridView` so this message doesn't show.

I have a `Clear` method that currently does this:

```
GeneralGridView.DataSource = Nothing
GeneralGridView.Columns.Clear()
GeneralGridView.DataBind()
```

But using that technique will show the `EmptyDataTemplate`

Is there any way I can clear the results from a GridView **without showing the Empty Template Message** and **without just reloading the entire page**?

Comment: I don't know how I can make that clearer!? How can I empty the data bound to a GridView without it using the EmptyDataTemplate - that should only be used after doing a search that returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could remove the empty template - you don't need it. It not clear if you simply don't want that template ever showing, or in fact you want to clear the grid, and not show the empty template WHEN you decide to clear the grid?

However, if the user can say enter data, and hit search, then it is RATHER NICE to have the no data show.

but, if you whack your own custom clear button, then the no data will show - so I kind of get your point. You can do this:

```
GridView1.DataSource = null;
GridView1.EmptyDataTemplate = null;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

so, your clear button will clear the grid - and NOT show no data template.

You find that if you do a search, and re-bind, then you still get/see the "no data" template, and as noted this is often desired for a search criteria that returns no data, but a clear button should not show "no data".

thus above should work fine.

Comment: Yes, that is EXACTLY what I wanted. I want it show NO MESSAGE when the "clear" button is pressed, but I want the message to show when the "search" button is pressed and NO RESULTS are found. I thought using `GridView1.EmptyDataTemplate = null` in code-behind would prevent the "search" showing "no results" but this actually isn't the case, thanks!!